# What is it called when you juxtapose meaning in a familiar phrase?

Tags: terminology

What is it called when you juxtapose meaning in a familiar phrase, or twist its meaning?

For example, "America has the best politicians that money can buy." or "A fool and his money are soon elected."

Comment: A joke? Being snarky? In my family, we call it “leaving no word unturned”—as opposed to “no stone.”

Comment: Eggcorns involve substitution rather than juxtaposition. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Comment: These are just plays on words. I'm not sure there's a specific term for this type.

Comment: There are some twisted proverbs at this [NIH website](https://kids.niehs.nih.gov/games/brainteasers/puzzling-proverbs/index.htm), for instance _A miss is as good as a ... Mr._ But no attempt at a class name. //  I remember _When the going gets tough, the tough go shopping._

Comment: To err is human - to forgive is not SAC policy - Gen Curtis LeMay. I think this is a productive idiom, where you can piggyback off a core phrase and customize it to a variety of situations. [Snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) is close, but it isn't usually ironic. You want a word for a *bent* snowclone. A snowclown?